# LazyVStack ScrollView Performance

Tags: ios, swiftui

The performance of a `LazyVStack` in a `ScrollView` is bad even with simple views. Whereas scrolling with a `VStack` is buttery smooth, scrolling with a `LazyVStack` is really choppy.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            // VStack {     // uncomment this to see the difference
            LazyVStack {    //
                ForEach(0..<1000, id: \.self) {
                    Text(String($0))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any tips for improving this performance? (I can't use a `List` for other reasons, and I can't use a `VStack` for the bad initial load performance)

Comment: I don't see any performance degradation / improvement using `VStack` or `LazyVStack`. Tested on iPhone 12 Pro device and simulator.

Comment: This was tested on an iPhone 7 and iPhone 7+, the deceleration is noticeably choppy. But I've now tested on iPhone X and it's barely noticeable. Very interesting.

Comment: Try restarting the phone, your code looks fine. If issue persists you could file a bug.